# How to combine usage of asp-all-route-data and a list of ids in query string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

In ASP.NET, `asp-all-route-data` is great for passing variables into an anchor tag. But now I am trying to add a list of ids and not having much luck. `asp-all-route-data` accepts an IDictionary<string, string> which cannot have duplicate keys. But I need to bind to a list from query string such as `?myParams=1&myParams=2` (as dictated by [ASP.NET out of the box model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#collections)).

```
var myParams = new List<int> {0,1,2};
var routeData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var myParam in myParams)
{
  routeData.Add(nameof(myParams), myParam.ToString());
}
```

I tried adding results in duplicate key exception.

```
var myParams = new List<int> {0,1,2};
var routeData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (var i = 0; i < myParams.Count; i++)
{
  var myParam = myParams[i];
  routeData.Add($"{nameof(myParams)}{i}", myParam.ToString());
}
```

results in no model binding.

Here's the razor for completeness:

```
<a asp-route="@routeName" asp-all-route-data="@routeData">click me</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

While researching the question further I actually found the answer, so will share it here.

It turns out I was quite close, but rather than a naming convention of

```
$"{nameof(myParams)}{i}"
```

It should have been

```
$"{nameof(myParams)}[{i}]"
```

as detailed in the [Microsoft documentation for model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#collections).

Full code example:

```
var myParams = new List<int> {0,1,2};
var routeData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (var i = 0; i < myParams.Count; i++)
{
  var myParam = myParams[i];
  routeData.Add($"{nameof(myParams)}[{i}]", myParam.ToString());
}
```

Which results in a query string (based on the route I have set up) of:

```
?myParams[0]=0&myParams[1]=1&myParams[2]=2
```